# error at runtime setting the size of an array in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I've got 2 arrays;

```
shared stringvar array dkrowarrray;

shared stringvar array newArray;
```

I know that the first array contains 10 elements.

When I try to set the value of newArray I get a runtime error (Error in formula deltakrow: 'shared stringvar array dkrowarray; ' An array's dimension must be an integer between 1 and 1000).  I'm trying to set it like;

```
numbervar dkrowarraysize := count(dkrowarray);//I also tried ubound here.

redim newArray[dkrowarraysize];
```

When I prescribe the value like `redim newArray[10];` then it runs OK, but the size of the array will need to change.

Why does crystal not like the int variable name between the square brackets?

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled dkrowarrray/dkrowarray. This worked for me:

```
shared stringvar array dkrowarrray := ["1","2","3","4","5"];
shared stringvar array newArray;

//5
ubound(dkrowarrray);
//0
ubound(newArray);

//3 ('rrr') lower-case 'r' characters in the name
numbervar dkrowarraysize := ubound(dkrowarrray);

//5
redim newArray[dkrowarraysize];
//5
ubound(newArray);
```